# How can I make spatial predictions for a raster stack with a 'lrm' model (rms package)?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, raster, prediction

I have fitted a logistic regression model using 'lrm' function of 'rms' package and I need to make spatial predictions for a stack of rasters (one for each of my predictors).

I've tried to use 'predict' function of 'raster' package but, although it seemed to work, its predictions were wrong.

```r
# First of all I fitted a lrm model with 7 predictors, each predictors was
# introduced in the model as a spline of 3 nodes (rcs(---, 3)):

model3<-lrm(pres~rcs(aspect,3)+rcs(fcc,3)+rcs(hli,3)+rcs(mde,3)
     +rcs(river,3)+ rcs(slope,3)+rcs(clim3,3),data=cal1,x=T,y=T)

# Secondly I made a stack of rasters, one for each of the predictors

RastDat<-stack(aspect,fcc,hli,mde,river,slope,clim3)

# And finally I tried to make predictions for RastDat with 'predict'
# function of 'raster' package

AcePred<-predict(RastDat, model3, type="fitted.ind")
```

The function produces a raster but the values of that raster do not match with the predictions obtained with the model for each pixel when 'predict' function of the 'rms' package is directly used.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: try `type="response"` inside of the predict function.